# I code a discord bot with discord.js and i have the error "Cannot read property 'set' of undefined" with my commnd handler

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I followed a tutorial and yet even the creator does not know what is wrong with the code ...

`Code` : https://pastebin.com/rjrEJ129

`Error + Console log of getFileName` : https://pastebin.com/cSqCJQEg

`Console log of commands` : https://pastebin.com/GKeyUH9H

If i remove the for loop and the code in it, the bot read correctly all my commands so i don't know where is the mistake. This is not a keyboard error. I spent 4 hours on it without success so if someone could help me I would be delighted. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main js file you have to set `bot.commands` as a collection/map

index.js

```js
const { Collection, Client } = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Client();
bot.commands = new Collection();
```

> I spent 4 hours

that's what happens when you try a library without a good knowledge of js and debugging first, this was a pretty straight forward error message.

Comment: Oh, well, uh, i just removed the bot.commands and i forgot to re add it.. my bad, thanks.

Comment: @Prole1997 no problem, accept the answer if it solved your problem.